# rss feed with jquery won't wrap into list

Tags: jquery-mobile, rss, html-lists, word-wrap

I'm using Yahoo Pipes to work around the cross-domain issue when retrieving an RSS feed with jquery. Here's my script:

```
     function getFeed(feed) {
        var newScript = document.createElement('script');
            newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
            newScript.src = 'http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/9oyONQzA2xGOkM4FqGIyXQ/run?   &_render=json&_callback=piper&feed='+feed;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newScript);
     }     
     function piper(feed) {
        var tmp='<li>';
        for (var i=0; i<feed.value.items.length; i++) {
          tmp+='<a href="'+feed.value.items[i].link+'">';
          tmp+=feed.value.items[i].pubDate;
          tmp+='<h3>'+feed.value.items[i].title+'</h3>';
          tmp+='<p>'+feed.value.items[i].description+'<br></p>';
          tmp+='<br></a></li>';
          tmp+='<br>';
          tmp+='<li>';
        }
        document.getElementById('rssLayer').innerHTML=tmp;
     }
```

And here's how I'm calling it in the body:

```
<body class="ui-body" onLoad='getFeed("http://file.xml")';"> 

<ul data-role="listview" id='rssLayer'></ul>

</body>
```

My problem is that the text within each **li** won't wrap. Several of the descriptions are quite long, and most get cut off. Is there a way to wrap text in an **li** with CSS? I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple...I could look for a different way to display the feed, but I'd like to understand what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for elements where you want to wrap the text.

```
style="white-space:normal !important;"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had "white-space:normal", and no idea why it wouldn't work. Adding !important made the difference.